# Unable to Put the Count Formula linked with count of next column details

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, countif, excel-2013

[image]

Please help me to place the correct formula, What I'm looking is below
in B3 i placed formula to show todays date "=Today()"
in B4 I placed the formula "=COUNTIF(G11:G15, TODAY())" to count all number of events on todays date

Issue is to further distribution of the count in Cell B4 as there are 3 timings (Morning, Mid-Day, Evening) mentioned in Column H11:H15 (adjacent to different dates in Column G11:G15), so 3 things to count on

1. count the no of call backs in Mornings on today date in (B5)
2. count the no of call backs in Mid-Day CBs on today date in (B6)
3. count the no of call backs in Evening CBs on today date in (B7)

I tried to put countif but its counting all entries in the column range H11:H15 but not excluding the entries that are not on todays date.

Example : Todays Date is 26-Jan-2024 mentioned in cell B3, and there is a range of different dates in Column G11:G15 and call back timings in Column H11:H15, so need to find the correct formula for below mentioned cells

Morning CBs (B5)
Mid-Day CBs (B6)
Evening CBs (B7)

Please help me find the correct formulas
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use **[COUNTIFS()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)** function in excel

Comment: Hey Mayukh thank you so much for your immediate response, it worked

Comment: This is the formula you need to use: `=COUNTIFS(G11:G15,B3,H11:H15,SUBSTITUTE(A5:A7," CBs",))` or, `=COUNTIFS(G11:G15,B3,H11:H15,TEXTBEFORE(A5:A7," "))`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `COUNTIFS()`

[image]

---

```
=COUNTIFS(G11:G15,B3,H11:H15,SUBSTITUTE(A5:A7," CBs",))
```

---

Or,

```
=COUNTIFS(G11:G15,B3,H11:H15,TEXTBEFORE(A5:A7," "))
```

---